# Permissible to install 90 squeeze connector to a junction box face plate?

Tags: junction-box, connectors

Installing a residential wall oven metal flex conduit to a metal junction box that is recessed flush with the drywall.  Is it permissible to attach a 90 degree squeeze connector to the box cover plate knock out versus removing the J box outward to access the side knockouts. If yes, is a separate ground wire to the cover plate required?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is OK with a 90º connector into the box cover plate knock out. *As long as the metal j-box is properly grounded* the metal cover does not need any additional grounding. The grounding is connected through the metal to metal of the cover plate to the box and also the metal screws holding the cover plate on.

Comment: The screws don’t count for anything re: grounding.

Comment: Thanks Kyle, box will be green screw grounded.   Also checking if a box extender with a straight strain relief connector out a top KO  is an option, although limited on depth clearance between the drywall  and oven back.

Comment: I would not bother with the box extender. We always do ovens exactly as you have stated- with a 90º connector off the covert for exactly that reason- the depth clearance.